# Is it possible to link to the acronym definition without using the full acronym

Tags: cross-referencing, acronyms, links

I'm trying to be a bit fancy with the [acronym](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/acronym/?lang=en) package.
I have several acronyms defined (I dump an example below) and I'd like to make a link to the acronym definition from my text, but for the first letter of the acronym rather than the whole thing.

So my acronym is "S-wave" and I'd like to find some way to write "S" and link it to the acronym.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\acused{swave}\acused{pwave}\acused{dwave} % mark as used for this example

I'd like to have the `S' linked to the entry for the acronym `S-wave' in the following sentence.

The system comprises of both S- and \ac{pwave} components. By contrast, the \ac{dwave} contribution is negligible.

\lipsum[3]

\section*{List of acronyms}
\begin{acronym}
  \acro{swave}[S-wave]{the $K\pi$ system in a scalar, $J=0$ state}
  \acro{pwave}[P-wave]{the $K\pi$ system in a vector, $J=1$ state}
  \acro{dwave}[D-wave}{the $K\pi$ system in a tensor, $J=2$ state}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `hyperref`'s `\hyperlink{link target}{link text}`:

```
\hyperlink{swave}{S}
```

A little benefit is to use `acronym`'s internal macro `\AC@hyperlink{link target}{link text}`. This has the small benefit that is gives to error if `hyperref` isn't loaded.

The only thing you need then is a suitable wrapper

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\aclink{\AC@hyperlink}
\makeatother
```

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\aclink{\AC@hyperlink}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\acused{swave}\acused{pwave}\acused{dwave} % mark as used for this example

I'd like to have the `S' linked to the entry for the acronym `S-wave' in the
following sentence.

The system comprises of both \aclink{swave}{S}- and \ac{pwave}
components. By contrast, the \ac{dwave} contribution is negligible.

% or:

The system comprises of both \hyperlink{swave}{S}- and \ac{pwave}
components. By contrast, the \ac{dwave} contribution is negligible.

\lipsum[3]

\section*{List of acronyms}
\begin{acronym}
  \acro{swave}[S-wave]{the $K\pi$ system in a scalar, $J=0$ state}
  \acro{pwave}[P-wave]{the $K\pi$ system in a vector, $J=1$ state}
  \acro{dwave}[D-wave]{the $K\pi$ system in a tensor, $J=2$ state}
\end{acronym}

\newpage\null % add an empty page so we can see the links go to the right place

\end{document}
```

Comment: @greeneggs you're welcome :)